# Solve $x^2-y!=2001$ over the positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Solve $x^2-y!=2001$ over the positive integers.

Can anyone give me hint for this question, I am quite new to diophantine equations so please excuse me .

Comment: $(x,y)=(45,4)$ is fairly easy to spot. The question is, is it the only solution?

Comment: Hint: after some point, $y!$ is divisible by $9$. But $2001$ is only divisible by $3$.